# Is there any way to have confidential clients using javascript-adapter

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am very aware that you can't store your secret on a front end app, however, is there any way to work around this thus still having the benefits while using the javascript adapter.

I'm guessing using the JWT token option lead to the same issue.

I've read about using 2 different clients, one as a confidential admin and the other as a public client. All though I don't see how it is any better as the secret will still be held publicly, just in a different location.

Should I look deeper into this, are there any other workaround ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution : This won't turn your client into a confidential one, but you can add a layer of security by using PKCE.